# Convert color to image?

Tags: javascript, java, xml, colors, background-color

I have a problem: The APK that I want to change has a background color (white). Changing the color is not a problem for me, I am able to change the color to black, pink, blue, whatever. But I would like to convert the color into a picture so that you have a picture as a background. How is that possible?

Comment: Could you give us a bit more information? Like, what the APK is, what you are developing (Website or Mobile app), or its purpose, or maybe the code you are already using to change the background color? That sort of stuff.

Comment: The question is not clear enough. There are many possible answers to this question. And what programming language should be used Java or JavaScript?

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks for the quick answers! The program is an Android APK, the program is not very big, only 1 MB. I edit the APK with MT Manager and have not learned it myself. But I didn't steal it either, that's what she thinks now. It is an auto clicker where the background is white. In Resources> Color I find the background color, but I don't know how I can convert it into a PNG or insert a picture there so that it becomes the color beforehand, a picture. Is it possible that I just send you the APK?

Comment: Editing APKs is not a productive approach to app developing.(It's very hard actually) Where did the APK originate in the first place? That's where you can make edits like this easiest.

Comment: The Packagename is simplehat.clicker     its a very low APK 1mb

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use to make an image of a specific color (any color):

```
/**
 * Creates a Color Icon image.
 * All colors to this method must be provided in in hexadecimal format.<br>
 * 
 * @param hexColor (String) A hexadecimal Color value (ex: #FFFFFF  - The color white) you want to turn into an Icon.<br>
 * 
 * @param width (Integer - int) The desired width of the image.<br>
 * 
 * @param height (Integer - int) The desired height of the image.<br
 * >
 * @param borderOptions (Optional - String - To Options)<pre>
 * 
 *      borderColor     - Default is black (#000000). You can set whatever 
 *                        border color you like as long as it is supplied 
 *                        in hexadecimal.
 * 
 *      borderThinkness - Default is "0" (No Border). You can set whatever 
 *                        border thickness you like as long as it is a String
 *                        representation of a integer value (ex: "3").</pre><br>
 * 
 * @return (Icon) A javax.swing.icon type is returned of the supplied color. 
 * Convert this to whatever image type you like or use in your component's 
 * 'setIcon()' method as is.
 */
public static javax.swing.Icon colorToIcon(String hexColor, int width, int height, String... borderOptions) {
    java.awt.Color borderColor = java.awt.Color.decode("#000000");
    float borderThickness = 0;
    if (borderOptions.length > 0) {
        // Border Color
        if (borderOptions.length >= 1) {
            if (borderOptions[0] != null) {
                if (!borderOptions[0].startsWith("#")) {
                    borderOptions[0] = "#" + borderOptions[0];
                }
                borderColor = java.awt.Color.decode(borderOptions[0]);
            }
            // Border Thickness
            if (borderOptions.length >= 2 && borderOptions[1] != null && borderOptions[1].matches("\\d+")) {
                borderThickness = Float.valueOf(borderOptions[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    java.awt.image.BufferedImage img = new java.awt.image.BufferedImage(width, height,
                                       java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    java.awt.Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
    g2d.setColor(java.awt.Color.decode(hexColor));
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    if (borderThickness > 0) {
        g2d.setColor(borderColor);
        g2d.setStroke(new java.awt.BasicStroke(borderThickness));
        int bwOffset = 0, bhOffset = 0;
        if ((int) borderThickness > 0) {
            bwOffset = (int) borderThickness / 2;
            bhOffset = bwOffset;
        }
        g2d.drawRect(0 + bwOffset, 0 + bhOffset, width - (int) borderThickness, height - (int) borderThickness);
    }
    javax.swing.Icon icon = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(img);
    g2d.dispose();
    return icon;
}
```

**How to Use:**

```
jLabel1.setIcon(colorToIcon("#FF00FF", 48, 48, "#000000", "1"));
```